# Ruby/Builder API: create XML without using blocks

Tags: ruby, xml, builder

I'd like to use [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) to construct a set of XML files based on a table of ActiveRecord models. I have nearly a million rows, so I need to use `find_each(batch_size: 5000)` to iterate over the records and write an XML file for each batch of them, until the records are exhausted. Something like the following:

```
filecount = 1
count = 0
xml = ""
Person.find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |person|
  xml += person.to_xml  # pretend .to_xml() exists 
  count += 1       

  if count == MAX_PER_FILE
    File.open("#{filecount}.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(xml) }
    xml = ""
    filecount += 1
    count = 0
  end
end
```

This doesn't work well with Builder's interface, as it wants to work in blocks, like so:

```
xml = builder.person { |p| p.name("Jim") }
```

Once the block ends, Builder closes its current stanza; you can't keep a reference to p and use it outside of the block (I tried). Basically, Builder wants to "own" the iteration.

So to make this work with builder, I'd have to do something like:

```
  filecount = 0
  offset = 0
  while offset < Person.count do
    count = 0
    builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(indent: 5)
    xml = builder.people do |people|
      Person.limit(MAX_PER_FILE).offset(offset).each do |person|
        people.person { |p| p.name(person.name) }
        count += 1
      end
    end

    File.open("#output@file_count.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(xml) }
    filecount += 1
    offset += count
  end
```

Is there a way to use Builder without the block syntax? Is there a way to programmatically tell it "close the current stanza" rather than relying on a block?

Comment: Don't use builder. XML is a simple format as long as you escape the xml entities correctly. Batch your db retrieve then just write out the batch as xml to a file handle. Don't buffer via a string as your example shows. Just write to the filehandle. Let the OS deal with buffering. Files can be of any size, why the limit? Also, don't include the indentation spaces, with million rows, they'd add up.

Comment: You have a point- Builder is adding more pain than it is relieving at this point. Just discovered Ruby's encode(:xml => :text) method, which truly makes it simple. As for the limit- I'm generating sitemaps, which have to be broken up into pieces < 50MB. There are also other business requirements for making the files in chunks rather than one large one.

Comment: I'm submitting my comment as an answer due to the upvotes and use of it. See below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: don't use builder.

XML is a simple format as long as you escape the xml entities correctly.

Batch your db retrieve then just write out the batch as xml to a file handle. Don't buffer via a string as your example shows. Just write to the filehandle. Let the OS deal with buffering. Files can be of any size, why the limit?

Also, don't include the indentation spaces, with million rows, they'd add up.

**Added** 
When writing xml files, I also include xml comments at the top of the file:

- The name of the software and version that generated the xml file
- Date / timestamp the file was written
- Other useful info. Eg in this case you could say that the file is batch # x of the original data set.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up generating the XML manually, as per Larry K's suggestion. Ruby's built-in XML encoding made this a piece of cake. I'm not sure why this feature not more widely advertised... I wasted a lot of time Googling and trying various `to_xs` implementations before I stumbled upon the built-in `"foo".encode(xml: :text)`.

My code now looks like:

```
  def run
    count = 0
    Person.find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |person|
      open_new_file if @current_file.nil?

      # simplified- I actually have many more fields and elements
      #
      @current_file.puts "     <person>#{person.name.encode(xml: :text)}</person>"

      count += 1

      if count == MAX_PER_FILE
        close_current_file
        count = 0
      end
    end

    close_current_file
  end

  def open_new_file
    @file_count += 1
    @current_file = File.open("people#{@file_count}.xml", 'w')
    @current_file.puts "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
    @current_file.puts "     <people>"
  end

  def close_current_file
    unless @current_file.nil?
      @current_file.puts "     </people>"
      @current_file.close
      @current_file = nil
    end
  end
```